# How can i install nodeJs in linux ı am getting error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, linux, policy

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp4am.png)

I try everything but ı am gettin this error what i have to do ?

apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get-update etc. etc.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
policykit-1 : Depends: libpolkit-agent-1-0 (= 0.105-26ubuntu1.2) but 0.105-26ubuntu1.3 is to be installed
Depends: libpolkit-gobject-1-0 (= 0.105-26ubuntu1.2) but 0.105-26ubuntu1.3 is to be installed

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on askubuntu.com

Comment: Also: don't link to the error, include it (as text) in the body of the question. This helps us understand what the problem is, protects against link rot, makes it discoverable by search engines, and is more accessible to (e.g.) people with screen readers.